# Понимание CredSSP

Tags: qt, rdp

Здравствуйте. В учебных целях пытаюсь написать свою реализацию RDP клиента. Изучил спецификацию RDP протокола и попытался написать собственный клиент. Но застопорился на банальной авторизации. После просмотра дампов wireshark я понял, что в самом начале посылая negotiation request мы отправляем поддерживаемые способы шифрования. 0x00 стандартное RDP шифрования. 0x01 TLS, 0x02, CredSSP. Как я понял, CredSSP является самым продвинутым, поэтому решил идти по последнему пути. По спецификации после согласования методов аутентификации идет обычное TLS рукопожатие, после которого нужно отправить серверу SPNEGO token. Для TLS рукопожатия я использую просто QSslSocket. Но что это за SPNEGO token в упор понять не могу. Пожалуйста кто знает, объясните насколько это возможно, на пальцах, как проходит аутентификация по CredSSP уже неделю не могу с этим справиться.

Comment: SPNEGO token если совсем грубо  - он необходим для корректного поддержания сессии между сервером и клиентом. Основное назначение - чтобы сервер всегда понимал, с кем имеет дело в данный момент, и что ему выдать, а в чем отказать :)

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ. Правильно ли я понимаю, что это просто некая рандомная последовательность, по которой затем клиент и сервер будут друг друга идентифицировать? Просто я нигде не могу найти пример этого токена. Если не сложно, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно его генерировать и отправлять, или как он выглядит вообще?)

Comment: Едиснтвенное за что можно зацепиться слёту: https://github.com/petRUShka/spnegohelp/blob/master/spnego.h

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое) Буду изучать)